# XDocument Linq Query to construct a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

Below is my xml from which i would like to build a dictionary where it should be something like

Dictionary structure

key = "A" Value = "1" 
....
key = "F" Value = "6".

Im just not able to figure it . Can someone help please ?.

```
<Overrides>
  <token key="A" value="1"/>
  <token key="B" value="2"/>
  <token key="C" value="3"/>
  <token key="D" value="4"/>
  <token key="E" value="5"/>
  <token key="F" value="6"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure:

```
// Where "element" is the Overrides element
var dictionary = element.Elements("token")
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("key").Value,
                                      x => x.Attribute("value").Value);
```

Comment: Just want to point out that this will throw an exception if there are duplicate key attributes in the XML.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Yes, indeed. If you want to be able to track multiple values for the same key, you can use ToLookup instead.